# Asp Mvc application throwing Server Error '/' in Application following assumed restart

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Ok, been brooding over this for a few hours now, but I can't seem to grasp it.

I have an ASP MVC application which throws a **Server Error '/' in Application** error after being left alone for 5 - 10 minutes. I assumed this was due to an issues reloading the configuration following an Application Pool recycle, however I have disabled that function on IIS, and the issue persists. The odd thing is though, that if you refresh the page, it works fine.

Here's the stack trace (app name replaced with TEST_APP):

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error    occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +356
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +117
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +267
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +318
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +211
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +393
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user) +59
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe() +43
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode() +27
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +70
System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +50
TEST_APP.Models.Account.checkIP() +696
TEST_APP.Controllers.BaseController.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) +197
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive(Int32 filterIndex) +268
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__31(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +93    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +170
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +292
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +1167
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +170
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +455
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +42
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +67
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +170
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +897
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +170
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +711
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +94
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +67
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +170
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +555
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +921
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137
```

Any ideas guys?

**Edit:**
I've tried commenting out this particular method, but it simply trips on the following db call. It's like it needs that first error to establish the connection

**Edit 2:** Example connection

```
  using (DBDataContext test_context = new DBDataContext ())
  {
    var result = (from a in test_context.GetTable<test_table>()
                 select a).FirstOrDefault();
    if (result != null)
    {
        // Do Foo
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Do you have database connection issues? OR maybe you have a leaky connection?

Comment: No connection issues that I'm aware of. I can run commands based on this connection string, and the application runs fine after tripping once. I've tested with 20+ synchronous connections and all appear ok

Comment: How are you creating and destroying your database connections?

Comment: Edited question to show example